# Ninject: What happens to non-disposable InRequestScope and InTransientScope objects after the HTTP request is finished?

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have searched a lot about these question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434984/when-is-a-transient-scope-object-deactivated-in-ninject) and a lot of other places, but not getting everything I want to know!

1. From a WebApi project point-of-view, when are `InTransientScope` objects Created? In the Ninject docs it is stated that such objects are created whenever requested, but in a web api project that handles HTTP requests, the instance is created at the request start time so in this regard it is the same as `InRequestScope` then?
2. In a WebApi project, is it okay to use `InTransientScope` objects knowing that they will never be kept track of by Ninject? If Ninject never keeps track of Transient objects, then what is the purpose of this scope and what happens to such objects after they have been used?
3. If I declare an object with InRequestScope and that object doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface, what happens to such object after the web request has completed? Will it be treated the same way as an `InTransientScope` object?
4. Are different scopes to be used for: WebApi controllers, Repositories(that use a `InRequestScope` Session that is created separately) and Application services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two purposes for scopes:

1. Only allow one object to be created per scope
2. (optionally) dispose of the object once the scope ends.

As said, the disposal is optional. If it doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface it's not being disposed. There's plenty of usecases for that.
The `InTransientScope` is the default scope - the one being used if you don't specify another one. It means that every time a type `A` is requested from the kernel one activation takes place and the result is returned. The activation logic is specified by the binding part that follows immediately after the `Bind` part (`To<...>`, `ToMethod(...)`,...).
However, this is not necessarily at the time the web-request starts and the controller is instanciated. For example, you can use factories or service location (p.Ex. `ResolutionRoot.Get<Foo>()`) to create more objects after the controller has been created. To answer your questions in short:

1. When: When a request takes place or whenever your code asks for a type from Ninject either directly (`IResolutionRoot.Get(..)`) or through a factory. As `InTransientScope` objects are not being tracked they will not be disposed, however, if they are not disposable and the entire request code requests only one `IFoo` then practically there's is no discernible difference (apart from the slight performance hit due totracking `InRequestScope()`-ed objects)
2. As long as you don't need to make sure that instances are shared and/or disposed this is completely fine. After they are not being used anymore, they will get garbage-collected like any object you would `new` yourself.
3. When the scope ends ninject will remove the weak reference to the non-`IDisposable` object. The object itself will not be touched - just like when bound `InTransientScope()`
4. That depends on your specific requirements and implementation details. Generally one needs to make sure that long-scoped objects don't depend on short-scoped objects. For example, a Singleton-Service should not depend on a Request-scoped object. As a baserule, everything should be `InTransientScope()` unless there's a specific reason why it should not be. The reason will dictate what scope to use...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.